# h2ogpt custom Prompt wrong: invalid syntax. Maybe you meant '==' or ':=' instead of '='? (<unknown>, line 1)

Tags: python, large-language-model, h2ogpt

my prompt looks like this:

```
GPT4 User: {prompt}<|end_of_turn|>GPT4 Assistant:
```

I tried to set it up like this:

```
--prompt_type=custom \
--prompt_dict="{humanstr=GPT4 User: ,terminate_response=<|end_of_turn|>, botstr=GPT4 Assistant: }" \
```

but getting the error:

```
  File "/h2ogpt_conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 475, in _Fire
    component, remaining_args = _CallAndUpdateTrace(
  File "/h2ogpt_conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 691, in _CallAndUpdateTrace
    component = fn(*varargs, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/src/gen.py", line 1215, in main
    get_generate_params(model_lower,
  File "/workspace/src/gen.py", line 4015, in get_generate_params
    raise RuntimeError("Prompt wrong: %s" % error0)
RuntimeError: Prompt wrong: invalid syntax. Maybe you meant '==' or ':=' instead of '='? (<unknown>, line 1)
```

I am following the guide [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2ogpt/blob/main/docs/FAQ.md#adding-prompt-templates).

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the following code into Python

```py
{humanstr=GPT4 User: ,terminate_response=<|end_of_turn|>, botstr=GPT4 Assistant: }
```

gives the exact same error: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Maybe you meant '==' or ':=' instead of '='?".

Therefore, try using a valid Python syntax for the dictionary:

```py
{'humanstr': 'GPT4 User:', 'terminate_response': '<|end_of_turn|>', 'botstr': 'GPT4 Assistant:'}
```

The command would be

```
--prompt_type=custom \
--prompt_dict="{'humanstr': 'GPT4 User:', 'terminate_response': '<|end_of_turn|>', 'botstr': 'GPT4 Assistant:'}" \
```

Comment: it runs the model but doesn't work...model hallucinates...but changing it to pythonic version is the way forward. thanks